# Path to texmf folder

Tags: texlive, texmf

I am using TeXlive 2017, which is frozen by now. I was missing a package `subfigure.sty`.
In order to do a manual install,
 - I downloaded the `package.zip` from ctan website,
 - I made a directory `/home/texmf/tex/local` and unzipped the package into it.
 Then I have runned `texhash`, which created a file with contents,

```
% ls-R -- filename database for kpathsea; do not change this line.
./:
.:
ls-R
tex


./tex:
latex

./tex/latex:
local

./tex/latex/local:
subfig

./tex/latex/local/subfig:
Makefile
README
subfig.dtx
subfig.ins
subfig.pdf
subfigure.sty
test1.tex
test2.tex
test3.tex
test4.tex
test5.tex
test6.tex
test7.tex
 "
This the output of texhash command
"texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/texmf-config/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/texmf-var/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

Now my texstudio editor cannot still seem to find the package. Do I need to add extra lines in bashrc or do what else.

Comment: check if your `$PATH` variable is set properly

Comment: Which operating system do you have?

Comment: Imho you should still be able to install missing packages with tlmgr. Beside this: What do you mean by "your editor can't find the package"? Do you get errors if you try to use it in a tex document?

Comment: "check if your $PATH variable is set properly" ,What should be present under $PATH? My OS is ubuntu. My tex studio does not seem to locate  the package.